# How can I teach QTP to treat a control as another similar control?

Tags: qtp

I have a third party check box control in my AUT that QTP does not recognize. Is there a way to have QTP treat it as a regular .NET check box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the HP > QTP > Dat directory there are XML configuration files for each of the plugins loaded into QTP.  The .NET file is called SwfConfig.xml.  In this file, you can tell QTP how to interact with the control types it sees. In this case, you can define the following:

```
<Control Type="ControlTypeName" MappedTo="SwfCheckBox"></Control>
```

Note that this will not work in all cases, but with lightweight similar controls, it is worth a try before writing your own implementation.

Comment: with the above answer... you have a option to create a Virtual object for that!It will be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @nidhi I made this into a comment, since you can't comment yet. When you get 50 rep you can though... thanks for sharing! :)